# creating inline table valued function sql-server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

i want to create an inline table valued function using following statement

```
    USE [abc]
    GO
    /****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fnspEmpPeriodSkus]    Script Date: 04/14/2011 16:26:19 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnspEmpPeriodSkus] 
    (   
        -- Add the parameters for the function here
        @PositionID int
    )
    RETURNS TABLE 
    AS
    RETURN 
    (


declare @PeriodTypeID int
select @PeriodTypeID = cofig.PeriodTypeID from sysMarketSaleConfigurations config inner join setupJobs j on j.JobID = config.JobID
inner join setupDesignations d on d.JobID = j.JobID where d.DesignationID = @PositionID

SELECT EmployeeID,EmployeeName, ZoneID,Zone,RegionID,Region,TerritoryID,Territory,    StartDate, EndDate, empperiods.PeriodID, empperiods.DesignationID, EmpSkus.SKUID, EmpSkus.SKUCode, EmpSkus.Title, EmpSkus.GroupName, 
                                             EmpSkus.ProductGroupID, EmpSkus.PositionID,EmpSkus.PositionTitle 
FROM          (SELECT     StartDate, EndDate, PeriodID, DesignationID
                                                   FROM          (SELECT     sysPeriods.PeriodID, sysPeriods.StartDate, sysPeriods.EndDate, setupDesignations.DesignationID
                                                                           FROM          setupJobs INNER JOIN
                                                                                           setupDesignations ON setupJobs.JobID = setupDesignations.JobID CROSS JOIN
                                                                                           sysPeriods
                                                                           WHERE     Year(sysPeriods.StartDate) = Year(Current_timestamp) and (sysPeriods.PeriodTypeID = @PeriodTypeID)) AS drvtbl) AS empperiods LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                      dbo.vwEmpSkus AS EmpSkus ON 
                                                  empperiods.DesignationID = EmpSkus.PositionID
    )
```

but it gives me following error: incorrect syntax near keyword declare.
**Question**: is it possible to do in inline table valued function what i want to do ( declare a variable and get its result from query using parameter of function) then passing this value to main query that will calculate the result)? if yes how? if no what are choices multi statement table valued function or something else. i appreciate suggestions and other ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't declare variables within an inline table valued function.

Though you could just combine the 2 queries into 1 - looks like you should just be able to combine that initial select into the subquery where you currently use the variable.

Comment: can u explain how can i replace it with subquery